# Counting the number of occurences parameterized the column

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I am trying to create a groupby aggregation that takes as input a set of columns indices, `lhs`, and a single column `rhs`. What I would like to do is output two aggregations:

1. groupby the LHS, and count all the distinct occurrences of the columns values.
2. For the results from (1) where the count > 1, groupby the LHS + RHS and count all the distinct occurences of all of the columns column values,

For example, with the following table:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 300 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 101 | 300 | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | 101 | 300 | 3 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 300 | 4 |
| 3 | 30 | 300 | 300 | 5 |

Given input `vec![0,1], 2`, the output should be

| A | B | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | 30 | 1 |

And then the second aggregation should output

| A | B | C | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 101 | 1 |

Right now I have the following code which works for the first part:

```
fn get_aggregation(lhs: &Vec<usize>, rhs: usize, df: &DataFrame) {

    let lhs_names: Vec<_> = lhs.iter().map(|&i| col(df.get_column_names()[i])).collect();
    let rhs_name = col(df.get_column_names()[rhs]);

    let out = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .groupby(&lhs_names)
        .agg([rhs_name.count()])
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", out);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 11  ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I was trying to rename the column, and was unable to have the column renamed to "count".

For the second aggregation, I tried the following:

```
fn get_aggregation_2(lhs: &Vec<usize>, rhs: usize, df: &DataFrame) {

    let mut lhs_names: Vec<_> = lhs.iter().map(|&i| col(df.get_column_names()[i])).collect();
    let rhs_name = col(df.get_column_names()[rhs]);

    let out = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .groupby(&lhs_names)
        .agg([rhs_name.clone().count()])
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", out);

    lhs_names.push(rhs_name.clone());

    let out2 = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .groupby(&lhs_names)
        .agg([rhs_name.clone().count()])
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", out2);
}
```

I get the error:
 `Err(Duplicate(ErrString("column with name 'C' has more than one occurrences\n\nError originated just after this operation:\nDF [\"A\", \"B\", \"C\", \"D\"]; PROJECT */5 COLUMNS; SELECTION: \"None\"")))`

I first tried :
`df.clone().lazy().grupby(&lhs_names).agg([col(*).count()])`, but this outputs all of the remaining columns in the table. I just want the count for the rows that are in the projection of the list of attributes.